# Access Spotify programmatically?

Tags: ruby, spotify

I've been trying to sort out a way to access a Spotify client's information (running on the same computer). For example, I'd like to be able to tell the name of the current song, how far into the song it's playing is, that sort of thing. Is this possible? Ideally using Ruby...

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify

Comment: I believe that's for accessing the web API no? It seems that is used for modifying playlists and whatnot, *not* interacting with the Spotify client running on a computer.